# Folder access in group policy Windows XP

Tags: group-policy, filesystems

Is there any way I can set a group policy that gives a user restricted access to some folders in shared system?

Can I know all the folders a user has access to in my system, is there a tool like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Active Directory is in use, you should use group memberships to manage access.  That way you can go to one central location to see who has access and can remove someone's permissions withouth having to touch individual folder ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into using xcacls as part of a script. You can specify at logon what permissions you wish them to have.

This same tool can also be used to display permissions.

[MS KB for Xcacls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754)